# Ring buffers of android logcat

Tags: android, logcat, circular-buffer

The result of data below is from "adb logcat -d -b V:*". As I know, each of ring buffers - 'main, system, crash, events, radio is separate. But as you can see, log data is continuous. How can I explain them?

```
--------- beginning of events

06-25 09:26:16.738  3000  3000 I battery_saving_stats: [0,0,0,105041,7410,0,74408408,3256695,99]

...

06-25 09:46:35.272  3000 24526 I am_nandswap: [16421,com.google.android.youtube,3,7842017280,250,8,392ms,3,[261, 200693, 654767, 28855104, 527311, 417209, 28385536, 375553],5287872,4394452,[261, 204292, 654767, 28858752, 538509, 417209, 28389184, 386751],5284224,4362232]

--------- beginning of radio

06-25 09:46:35.347  3000  4659 W AccessNetworkUtils: Band and the range of EARFCN are not consistent: band = 7 ,earfcn = 0 ,isUplink = true

...

06-25 10:01:43.264  3000  4190 I wm_add_to_stopping: [0,243208516,com.kakao.talk/.activity.chatroom.ChatRoomHolderActivity,completePauseLocked]

--------- beginning of system

06-25 10:01:43.264  3000  3454 V DisplayPowerController[0]: Brightness [0.0] reason changing to: 'screen_off', previous reason: 'automatic'.

...

06-25 10:29:07.281  3000  3368 V WindowManager: performShowLocked: mDrawState=HAS_DRAWN in Window{8809388 u0 com.samsung.android.spay.pay.HintService}

--------- beginning of main

06-25 10:29:07.283  1887  9772 I EVA     : File: vendor/qcom/proprietary/cv-noship/eva/3.0/src/cpu/evaFaceDetection.cpp Line: 522 Function: evaFaceDetectionReadModel() Msg: /vendor/etc/eva/facedetection/model3.dat is used
```

I have no idea.

I think the result should show full data of each ring buffer.

Comment: Why are you surprised that "data is continuous"? A ring buffer is just a buffer that contains a certain number of entries. When a new entry is added the oldest entry is overwritten. As the "write pointer" returns to the begin of the buffer when it reaches the end this data structure is called "ring buffer" (as the write buffer looks like it goes in circles through the buffer). But that "ring property" is not visible to the user it is just how the buffer is organized internally. Thus I am not sure what you want to ask.

Comment: As I thought, each of "ring buffer" like "events, main, crash, system, radio" exist seperately. For example, if "radio ring buffer" exists seperately, not related to system and main ring buffer, the result should include current radio log after "06-25 10:01:43.264". But the result looks like each of ring buffer has order and some relations.